# How do I exclude static files from ASP.NET Core's authorization fallback policy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am currently developing an application where I have set up an authorization fallback policy to avoid having to set a policy on each controller individually. The problem is that you now have to be logged in to access the static files under "wwwroot" (where my frontend is) which is obviously wrong, since you need the frontend to be able login at all.

Is there a way to use the fallback policy but exclude the static files from it (e.g. somehow add AllowAnonymous to it)? Or am I on the wrong track and should solve this differently?

Edit: Accessing the static files directly (https://localhost:5001/index.html) works, but I am getting a 401 error when I call the root url (https://localhost:5001) and `MapFallbackToFile("index.html")`. Everything works fine if I comment out the fallback policy.

Here is my current Startup.cs (I am trying out .NET 6)

Authorization Service:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole(Roles.User)
        .Build();
});
```

Middleware:

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web v1"));
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHealthChecks("/health");

app.UseHangfireDashboard();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<UserMiddleware>();

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: I am not 100%, sure what you want to accomplish. It seems as though it is working as intended. Are you trying to have all razorpages/endpoints/etc have the fallback policy other than homecontroller controller and it's index method?

Comment: did you try to reorder the middlewares?

Comment: @mohammadreza yes I did, tried putting the MapFallbackToFile Middleware before Authorization and Authentication but that didn’t change anything

Comment: @Ben I want everything to have the fallback policy, other than what’s inside my wwwroot. I don’t have a HomeController and index method, because I want the root path to go to my JS frontend in the wwwroot

Comment: Not 100% sure this will give you what you want, but it did work for me when I wanted to have my static files without auth. Instead of a fallback policy, try this:

    services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("MyCustomPolicy")));

This will make it only apply to the Razor pages and controllers if the docs are right. Let me know if it works and I will put it as an answer.

Comment: @BenMatthews I think it works now and this definitely led me in the right direction. I needed to add the new Policy aswell though. This is my code now if you want to put it into your anwser (with a little bit of formatting :D )

Comment: ```builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
 options.AddPolicy("DenyAnonymous", new AuthorizationPolicy(
  new IAuthorizationRequirement[] { new DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement() },
  new string[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme }
 ));
}); 
builder.Services.AddControllers()
 .AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("DenyAnonymous")));```

Comment: @maiksch Added a generic answer for future use. Glad it ended up working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the auth only hit razor pages and controllers, and leaving your other files alone, this should accomplish that:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => 
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("MyCustomPolicy"))
);
```